# Cálculo de juros

Tags: c, c++, matemática

> [Engelbrecht et al., 2012] Elabore um programa que receba do usuário, o valor de uma aplicação e o valor da taxa de juros inicial. Considerando que essa taxa de juros aumenta 0,025% ao mês, então armazene em vetores, com 12 elementos cada:
>
> 1. O valor das taxas de juros em cada mês
> 2. O valor dos juros em cada mês
> 3. E o valor da aplicação corrigida em cada mês
>
> Após isso, mostre o valor inicial da aplicação e o conteúdo dos
>   vetores.
>
> Como faço esse programa? Não estou conseguindo fazer pra a taxa de
>   juros ir aumentando.
>
> *Ex: Mês 1 = 0,025%, Mês 2 = 0,050%, Mês 3 = 0,075%.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


int vetor[12];
float apini;
float txjini;
int num;


 int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   cout<<"Informe o valor da aplicacao inicial: "<<endl;
   cin>>apini;
   cout<<"Informe o valor da taxa de juros inicial: "<<endl;
   cin>>txjini;

  for(int i = 0; i<=12; i++)
  {
    txjini = (vetor[i]*0,025);
    cout<<"O valor das taxas de juros em cada mes e de:  "<<txjini<<endl;   
  }

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Alguém respondeu sua dúvida? Se sim, marque como respondida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a taxa de juros tem que variar a cada parcela então tem que usar uma variável que incrementa a parcela para calcular o novo juros, nada varia sem uma variação, o cálculo estava sendo feito sem isto. Ainda não estava considerando o valor aplicado e a taxa de juros inicial.

Fiz só a dúvida da pergunta. Melhorei a legibilidade do código. Não usei o *array* porque ele não é necessário para resolver a pergunta. E quando for criá-lo, é bem mais complicado do que estava fazendo, precisará criar uma `struct` ou `class` para cada parcela.

Tirando o *stream* este código é C e não C++.

[Não use ponto flutuante binário em valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Informe o valor da aplicacao inicial: " << endl;
    float ValorInicial;
    cin >> ValorInicial;
    cout << "Informe o valor da taxa de juros inicial: " << endl;
    float JurosInicial;
    cin >> JurosInicial;
    JurosInicial /= 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        cout << "O valor das taxas de juros em cada mes e de:  " << ValorInicial * (JurosInicial + 0.025 * i) << endl;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/taGrf6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nbskopzy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Math/Interest.cpp).

Comment: Amigo, obrigado! Ajudou demais aqui.....

Answer (score 0):

Você teria que armazenar a taxa de juros de cada mês em um *vetor* com 12 posições.

Ex.:

```
float txj[12];
```

E então no `for()` você faz assim:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
{
    txj[i] = (i + 1) * txjini;

    cout << "Juros do mes " << i << ": " << txj[i] << endl;
}
```

Mais ou menos isso. :)

Comment: Ajudou demais :D !
Matou a minha dúvida...

Comment: Que bom, @KennedyMedeiros! Precisando estamos aí. :D